# How to correctly get gulp.src globs from a variable?

Tags: variables, gulp, glob

Given the following Gulp setup

```
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');
var zip = require('gulp-zip');

var pkgDist = 'packages/';

function pkg(done) {
    src(['./**', '!node_modules/**', '!vendor/**', '!.gitignore', '!*.json', '!*.lock'], {base: '..'})
        .pipe(zip('archive.zip'))
        .pipe(dest(pkgDist))
    done();
};

exports.pkg = pkg;
```

how can I modify it in order to get `src` globs from a variable, i.e. `pkgSrc`, something like this:

```
[...]

var pkgSrc = <what to put here?>;

[...]

    src(pkgSrc)

[...]
```

I've tried to use this `var pkgSrc = " ['./**', '!node_modules/**', '!vendor/**', '!.gitignore', '!*.json', '!*.lock'], {base: '..'} ";` but it doesn't work.

---

If it's easier, I'm also open to solutions that result into this `src([pkgSrc], {base: '..'})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with just:

```
var pkgSrc = ['./**', '!node_modules/**', '!vendor/**', '!.gitignore', '!*.json', '!*.lock']
```

`gulp.src` first argument can be a string or an array, so now it is an array above.

The second argument is an object of options.  Include the options sepearately: `{base: '..'}`  so

```
src(pkgSrc, {base: '..'})
```

Comment: Thank you! It was easier than I expected.